# Is there a better way of structuring a functionality using BLoC?

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

Im wrote a bloc for a functionality that has a home page (that fetches a list of items) and a create/edit page (that creates/updates items).

My bloc is currently in charge of handling both pages since they belong to the same functionality, but my code is getting a little bit harder to read/write then usual because im handling 2 states at once.

```
class MeusSellersState extends Equatable {
  const MeusSellersState({
    this.home,
    this.form,
  });


  // Home and Form are my two states.
  final Home home;
  final Form form;

  MeusSellersState copyWith({
    Home home,
    Form form,
  }) {
    return MeusSellersState(
      home: home ?? this.home,
      form: form ?? this.form,
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [home, form];
}
```

I know i could separate this bloc in two, but im worried that more complex functionalities could  make me write several blocs and pollute even more my code.

Does anyone know a better solution ?

Comment: I would recommend making as many blocs as you need, don't worry about 'poluting' your code. Its a lot easier to manage 2 blocs with similiar features, than it is to manage 1 bloc for 2 pages with slightly different features. It will be easier to manage in the future if the features ever become more unique